# Transform date to valid format for PostgreSQL with PHP

Tags: php, date

I have a string in this format:

```
Thu, 26 Feb 2015 11:39:59
```

And I wonder if its possible to transform it to a valid timestamp format in order to insert it in my PostgreSQL database.

So ideally in the end I would have something like:

```
2015-03-26 11:39:59
```

Is there a function in PHP to do something like this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `DateTime()` to format date string.

```
$date = 'Thu, 26 Feb 2015 11:39:59';

$date = new DateTime($date);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I was not aware of this function and I was ready to do it with a much more complicated way.

Comment: Sidenote: to get the current date formatted as input to DateTime, use `date("Y-m-d h:m:s")`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use it as `DateTime::createFromFormat`

```
$date = 'Thu, 26 Feb 2015 11:39:59';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y H:i:s', $date);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //2015-03-26 11:39:59
```